# Limit of a sum of natural logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms

As the title says I have to calculate a limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\ln(1+x)+\ln(1+2x)+...+\ln(1+px)\right)^x$$

I've transformed the sum into one logarithm $\ln\left((1+x)(1+2x)...\right)$etc but I don't see how it helps me further. Some hints would be great.

Comment: Is $p$ a fixed constant?

Comment: Yes it is a fixed constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$\ln(1+x)\sim_0 x$$ we have

$$\left(\ln(1+x)+\ln(1+2x)+\cdots+\ln(1+px)\right)^x\sim_0\left(\frac{p(p+1)}{2}x\right)^x\\=\exp\left(x\ln\left(\frac{p(p+1)}{2}x\right)\right)\xrightarrow{x\to0}1$$

Comment: But why is ln(1+x) ~ 0^x?

Comment: Do you know that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1\quad?$$

Comment: Oh right I got it now thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\ln(1+t)\sim t$ as $t\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using sum-of-logs = log-of-product:

$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^p \ln{(1+nx)} = \ln(\prod_{n=1}^p (1+nx))
$$
$$
h(x) = e^{g(x)} = \prod_{n=1}^p (1+nx)
$$
and $(\ln a)^b = b\ln a$:
$$
f(x) = g(x)^x = (\ln h(x))^x = x \ln h(x)
$$

As $x\rightarrow 0$, each term in $h(x)$ approaches $1$, so $h(x)\rightarrow 1$, and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x \ln h(x) = 0 \times \ln(1) = 0\times 0 = 0.
$$